# Can't add a concrete instance of a generic interface to a generic collection

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I'll let the code do the talking:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    public interface IThing { } // can't change this - it's a 3rd party thing

    public interface IThingRepository<T> where T : class, IThing { } // can't change this - it's a 3rd party thing

    public interface IThingServiceInstance<T>
      where T : class, IThing
    {
        IThingRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThingServiceInstance<T> : IThingServiceInstance<T> where T : class, IThing
    {
        public IThingRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyThing : IThing
    {
    }

    class Test
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            IList<IThingServiceInstance<IThing>> thingServiceInstances = new List<IThingServiceInstance<IThing>>();
            // the following line does not compile. Errors are:
            // 1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<test.IThingServiceInstance<test.IThing>>.Add(test.IThingServiceInstance<test.IThing>)' has some invalid arguments    C:\TFS\FACE\ResearchArea\ArgonServiceBusSpike\Argon_Service_Bus_Spike_v2\Argon.ServiceLayer\test.cs 31  13  Argon.ServiceGateway
            // 2: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'test.ThingServiceInstance<test.MyThing>' to 'test.IThingServiceInstance<test.IThing>'    C:\TFS\FACE\ResearchArea\ArgonServiceBusSpike\Argon_Service_Bus_Spike_v2\Argon.ServiceLayer\test.cs 31  39  Argon.ServiceGateway
            // Why? ThingServiceInstance is an IThingServiceInstance and MyThing is an IThing
            thingServiceInstances.Add(new ThingServiceInstance<MyThing>());
        }
    }
}
```

If `ThingServiceInstance` is an `IThingServiceInstance` and `MyThing` is an `IThing`, why can't I add a `ThingServiceInstance<MyThing`> to a collection of `IThingServiceInstance<IThing>`?

**What can I do to make this code compile?**

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Search with keyword "Covariance and Contravariance"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThingServiceInstance<MyThing>` is **NOT** a subtype of `IThingServiceInstance<IMyThing>`, because `IThingServiceInstance<T>` is *invariant* in its type parameter `<T>`.

If you wanna make `ThingServiceInstance<MyThing>` a subtype of `IThingServiceInstance<IMyThing>`, then `T` has to be covariant.
In C#, you do that by declaring `IThingServiceInstance<T>` as such:

```
public interface IThingServiceInstance<out T>
```

**Edit**
This, however implies that `ThingServiceInstance<T>` can only return instances of T, but never have them as method arguments (hence the "out" notation).

**Edit2**

This is the gist of why your code wasn't compiling. As pointed out, since your `ThingServiceInstance<T>` exposes an `IThingRepository<T>` property, that too has to be covariant like so:

```
public interface IThingRepository<out T> where T : class, IThing { }
```

As follows, your property has to be get-only (remember, you can only *return* instances of `T`, or `U<T>` for that matter).

Comment: You need to change both interfaces to have covariant `T`. As it stands, your change does not compile with `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IThingServiceInstance<T>.Repository'. 'T' is covariant.`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to compile if you declare two of the interfaces coariant, and remove the setter from `IThingServiceInstance`.

Of course, you can't change the third party interface, so this doesn't really help.

```
public interface IThingRepository<out T> where T : class, IThing { } // can't change this - it's a 3rd party thing

public interface IThingServiceInstance<out T>
  where T : class, IThing
{
    IThingRepository<T> Repository { get; }
}
```

---

If `IThingRepository<T>` does not declare `T` covariant, then for

```
T : A
```

you don't get

```
IThingRepository<T> : IThingRespository<A>
```

and so you cannot have

```
IThingServiceInstance<T> : IThingServiceInstance<A>
```

since the type returned by the getter are not "compatible".

Comment: That's "covariant", not "contravariant".  Also, you don't need to remove the setter.

Comment: @D Stanley: If I leave the setter in, I get a compilation error: `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IThingServiceInstance<T>.Repository'. 'T' is covariant.`